# How can I call a minimize animation using a borderless window

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a Win32 API method where I can call the Minimize Animation to the taskbar (not the system tray) using a borderless window, when using the code:

```
WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

It just disappears, I want it to show a minimize animation instead of just closing out of nowhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use windows animations on borderless form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473489/use-windows-animations-on-borderless-form) and [Custom window style with minimize animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418160/custom-window-style-with-minimize-animation)