# How to implement minimizing a window on wpf by keeping windows animations

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to minimize a window to taskbar. the simplest way is using `WindowState`:

```
WindowState = WindowState.Minimized
```

But by doing this the window abruptly hides. Is there a way to implement minimizing a window on wpf by keeping windows animations (like other windows when we minimized by clicking minimize button on Titlebar).

Comment: You could get some hints from [Custom window style with minimize animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418160/custom-window-style-with-minimize-animation)

Comment: On my PC, `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized` triggers the default Windows animation. Are you sure animations are enabled in Windows settings? Check in sysdm.cpl - "Advanced system settings" - "Perfomance" button - The setting you want will be around the middle of the list. If it is checked, try unchecking and checking it again.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know,  there's no native API in Windows to trigger that animation.

1. You can try simulating the minimize event. The default hotkey for minimizing the focused window is <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>.
2. You can use [WPF animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to manipulate the window and recreate the minimize animation.