# Minimize window using Windows 11 animation effect

Tags: wpf, windows, .net-5, windows-11

There are two (it would seem) idiomatic ways to minimize a WPF window in code:

- `window.WindowState = window.WindowState.Minimized`
- `SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(window)`

The desired behavior is that the windows 11 window minimize animation is seen. The actual behavior is that the window instantly disappears from the screen.

**Please note**: This is for a window with a custom chrome - therefore triggering the behavior from code seems necessary:

```xml
<Window
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowTransparency="True
    Background="Transparent">

    <!-- custom windows chrome here  -->

</Window>
```

Is this a defect in the WPF desktop pack for .NET 5 (and 6)?

How does one not get the desired behavior without reverting back to default windows with standard chrome? It is not an option to use a WinUI 3.0 window since XAML islands have not been released yet and gradual modernization is needed.

There are some proposed solutions on the web, like:

- https://coderedirect.com/questions/352460/custom-window-style-with-minimize-animation

And the other (old) stackoverflow question:

- [Custom window style with minimize animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418160/custom-window-style-with-minimize-animation)

However, I could not get it to work with a window with a transparent background.

**===== update after issue was closed =====**

Reviewer: please read this carefully before voting to close the issue again and point to exact workable solution.

Issues with existing answers:

- First suggestion is to change WindowStyle, then WindowState; this poses a problem since it requires AllowTransparency=false which defeats the purpose of the exercise here - which is getting a custom chrome.
- Other suggestion is to use Win32 API's. Again I tried to do that but it did not work in my setting. I haven't logged the exact error messages I got though. However, looking at the code again there is an obvious issue with it: it has the same window requirement as the first suggestion: the window must not be transparent - observe code from the old answer:

  ```
  private IntPtr WindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
  {
      if (msg == ApiCodes.WM_SYSCOMMAND)
      {
          if (wParam.ToInt32() == ApiCodes.SC_MINIMIZE)
          {
              WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
              WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
              handled = true;
          }
          else if (wParam.ToInt32() == ApiCodes.SC_RESTORE)
          {
              WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
              WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
              handled = true;
          }
      }
      return IntPtr.Zero;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be on the roadmap in [Themes of .NET](https://themesof.net/) for .NET 7:

- [Epic - Support Windows 11 look and feel for WPF controls](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/5793)

Also this amazing piece of open-source just landed:

- [WPF UI](https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui) - Windows 11 styles and controls for WPF